# Perforce on Windows: find xargs add, list files in default cl for xargs, and backslashes

Tags: perforce

So I got Perforce up and running and made my first cl, but I am running into problems.

1. How do you use find in such a way that you can use `| xargs` directly into `p4 add`? At the time that I made the files, I was not thinking about using version control, so the file names contain spaces, apostrophes, and parentheses that have to be escaped before being passed into `p4 add`.
2. How do you list all of the files in the default cl in such a way that they can be passed to `xargs`? Also, is there a way to revert all of the files in the default cl?
3. My client is setup correctly, and the files to add are listed correctly in the cl. My client is at `/cygdrive/o/somefolder` (substituting instead of using actual names). One of the files in my cl is at `/cygdrive/o/somefolder/a/b.java`. However, when it goes to submit it, it tries to use `/cygdrive/o/somefolder\a\b.java`. What have I done wrong? Is there some setting somewhere for Windows setups?

Comment: You might want to consider breaking this up into several separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Lots in there but for this question,

1. Also, is there a way to revert all of the files in the default cl?

   `p4 revert -(a or c) default`

This should help, -c will revert all open files, while -a reverts unchanged/dont require integration type files.

If you have a mix and match of files you should considering creating a pending changelist, it assigns a number to it etc, so you can separate work for different efforts to different change lists.